# Inner join on nested select - when using same column multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a query that has an inner join on a nested select - however, the nested select itself needs to join on the same column twice, using the aliases val and val2.

I want to join the nested select on the 'id' column in val2, but how do I specify this? When I try the below query, I receive the error "**The column 'id' was specified multiple times for 'v'.**"

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2.

```
SELECT top 20 SUM(pagecount) AS totalPages, fullname, name FROM cas_sdr_history h
INNER JOIN cas_user_ext u ON h.accountid = u.x_id
INNER JOIN (select * from cas_val_assoc ass
        full outer join cat_validation val2 on ass.mainid = val2.id
        full outer join cat_validation val on ass.associd = val.id
        where mainid is not null
        and val2.name not in ('03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12')) v on v.id = u.x_id
WHERE trxdate BETWEEN '11/01/2015' AND '12/01/2015'
GROUP BY fullname, name
ORDER BY totalPages DESC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because 2 joined tables are same `column: id`

You must choose one of them. If you want to get all columns, you must use alias colums

Example: `val.id AS ID, val2.ID AS ID2`

Comment: I feel stupid now! Thanks for the answer, that worked perfectly.